# My current progress at my internship and my negative thinking

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, internship

This is not in the US.

I am currently a final year undergraduate, and part of my undergraduate program is to complete an internship. I started my internship (paid) at a small company from January this year. The internship is for one year.

The company is selling a desktop software. I am involved in developing a 'web based version' of that same software.

For the first 3 months. I was the only one doing software development for this web based software. Of course they do explain to me the business logic of the software.

But in terms of the programming language and technique needed to develop this new software, they only have a slight idea. Of course they can understand normal programming concepts, but they are not familiar with relatively newer programming languages and framework. They used to sell another web based software, but the person who implemented it is no longer employed with them.

So the first three months, I Googled, I went to Stack Overflow for help.

During this period of time, they told me things like 'you are not a good programmer', 'you should be faster'.

I told them I doubt myself, then they would say the important thing is for me to learn.

I mentioned the situation I faced to the faculty staff (from the university I am in) in charge of me. He told me I should stay in the position.

At around the 4th/5th month there, they hired developers with work experience, but only on a part time basis. They are also developing this new web based software.

But they are doing other parts of this big software, I am doing one other part of this software. I feel that they only hire them  because they  wanted to see how other people would implement it. Similar like 'getting a second opinion by visiting another doctor'. During this same period, someone from my school joined this same company. This person started the internship one trimester later than me.

Once again, they would say 'I understand you are learning, but you are slow'. They would say 'cost of development is expensive'

They would say 'this should be easy', 'I can develop my (desktop) software within a short period of time'.

I have to admit at certain times of our communication I have been exasperated and impatient. For I felt negative about this whole thing. My direct superior and the company's head don't seem to have a very good relationship. I feel that sometimes their goals are not in sync with each other.

There used to be very a strict habit of reviewing our work weekly, but after August (which is very recently), this seemed to have suddenly have stopped.

I think generally, I have a bit of negative thinking (a relic from my past). However, I don't really like the situation I am in right now. I am sort of like seeing how each day will go at the office... What do your think?

Comment: Hard to say from just a bit of text, but sounds like your company is trying to get this "new thing on the web all the cool kids are doing" on the cheap. They expect complete product development from an intern, well, tough luck.

Comment: How much time do you have left on your internship ? Would an option be to tough it out for the rest of the year ? You can always find something else afterwards

Comment: I think it could be re-opened, if the OP was to edit to clarify the question a bit more. If the real question is 'Should I quite my internship?', then it would be good to edit the title to say that.

Answer (score 6):

> I mentioned the situation I faced to the faculty staff(from the
>   university I am in) in charge of me. He told me I should stay in the
>   position.
>
> What do your think?

I think I agree with your faculty adviser. I think you should stick it out until the end of the year when your internship is completed. I think you are learning a lot about the real world of working. I think that learning has value.